# Align \footnote left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

At the moment my footnote looks like this

```
²Commit-Hooks definieren was die Softwareversionierung (zum Beispiel SVN) machen soll, sobald ein
  Commit passiert.
```

The second line just does not align to the first (C under C).
I do not get what have caused this.

My Code:

```
Commit-Hooks\footnote{Commit-Hooks definieren was die Softwareversionierung (zum Beispiel SVN) machen soll, sobald ein Commit passiert.}
```

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\begin{document}
Commit-Hooks\footnote{Commit-Hooks definieren was die Softwareversionierung (zum Beispiel SVN) machen soll, sobald ein Commit passiert.} 
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Koma-script classes have a mechanism for changing the setting of the footnotes.

The default is

```
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
```

and you can get the desired result by saying

```
\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}

Commit-Hooks\footnote{Commit-Hooks definieren was die Softwareversionierung
(zum Beispiel SVN) machen soll, sobald ein Commit passiert.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to push the footnote number to the left margin, you can do

```
\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{%
  \textsuperscript{\makebox[1em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}}
```

and the footnote would be

[image]

If you want the footnote number in the margin, you could use

```
\deffootnote[0em]{0em}{0em}{%
  \textsuperscript{\makebox[0em][r]{\thefootnotemark\ }}}
```

and the footnote would become

[image]

Comment: wow. i like this one the most as stated above. thanks to both of you. could you explain why 1em as a parameter changes so much and why it is not default behaviour?

Comment: @Wandang The default is a stylistic choice made by the class author.

Answer (score 7):

You could load the package `footmisc` with the `hang` option, as is done in the following example. (Note that I've slimmed down your not-quite-minimal example by omitting all of the `\usepackage` statements.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Commit-Hooks\footnote{Commit-Hooks definieren was die Softwareversionierung (zum Beispiel 
SVN) machen soll, sobald ein Commit passiert.} 
\end{document}
```

The amount of separation between the footnote number and associated text is controlled by the length parameter `\footnotemargin`; its default value is `1.8em`. The parameter may be changed via `\setlength` and/or `\addtolength` statements.

Note that this method works for both the `scrartcl` document class as well as many other document classes, including the other KOMA-Script classes and the "standard" LaTeX classes `article`, `report`, and `book`.

Comment: i added that userpackage but it seems texnic does have problems installing that package. i will try to manually install it and give feedback if it worked

Comment: @Wandang - Which TeX distribution, and which operating system, do you use?

Comment: i fixed it now. the packagemirror was offline and i needed to change it via miktex admin tool. now it is working like your screenshot. i liked the number beeing near the text more but this works too. at least aligned, thanks

Comment: @Wandang - I'm glad you were able to download the `footmisc` package. To reduce the space between the footnote number and text, you could issue a command such as `\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}`; the default value of this length parameter is `1.8em`.